# Parse from a file, where one of the columns has multiple value

Tags: c++

I'm trying to load the information from a text file into a vector. However, one of the columns has multiple values in it, and I'm having problem trying to retrieve the information from there. Below is my snippet code.

The text file will have format like this:
First column will be the name, and second column will be all the classes that he is taking right now. For the second column, I create a vector to hold it, but I don't know how to do a while loop condition for it. Can anyone help me please ?

```
mtingley    |art, music, math, history

while(getline(inUsers, textLine))
{
    Student s;
    string delimeter;
    // put the line into buffer string
    istringstream textStream(textLine);
    // get userName
    textStream >> userName;
    // read the buffer string till '|'
    getline(textStream, delimeter, '|');
    cout << userName << endl;
    s.SetUserName(userName);

    while() // need condition in this while loop
   {
        textStream >> subject;
        getline(textStream, delimeter, ',');
        vCourse.push_back(subject);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a good example here: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/53349/getline-with-multiple-delimiters